# Publish flash contents to Facebook stream

Tags: flash, facebook, share

I want to share some flash file hosted in my website to Facebook stream, as far I knew my domain should be whitelisted by Facebook but unfortunately I don't know who can I do that.

http://www.krotscheck.net/2009/12/21/how-to-publish-a-flash-application-to-the-facebook-stream.html

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a post using Graph API, you have to supply the following parameters, and invoke the Graph API Endpoint. There is a parameter named **video** which accepts any external video url (in supported formats) or **link to an swf file**

So I hope you got the idea on sharing the flash based content from an external domain.

```
if (accessToken) {
   var data = {
       method: 'feed',
       access_token:accessToken,
       link: link,
       picture: picture,
       name: name,
       caption: caption,
       description: description,
       to:to,
       from:from,
       source: video,
       actions:action
   }
   FB.api("/" + to + "/feed", 'post', data, function(response) {
       //check the response
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hasin, any permission I should take from facebook in order to do that?
In other word, in article I have provided in original post, the writer said

'If you paid especially close attention to the documentation linked above, you’ll also note that multimedia sharing won’t work if your domain is not whitelisted by Facebook. This is to protect Facebook from people who might want to distribute illegal content'

any idea about how to register my domain in facebook whitelist ?

Comment: no other permission but **publish_stream** - well it's hard to find if your domain is black listed. So you can find that only after trial-and-error :)

Comment: hummm, well, lets simplify our example, I tried to share the following flash file on facebook wall, I was expecting it should run like a youtube link, but unfortunately it didn't :( 
http://www.shoofbetak.com/projects/misc/Portosokhna1/porto.swf

on the same time when I tried to share a youtube link 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1kdUs7aiAw&feature=related
it works fine. 
hope you have got my point.